# Alguna Librería de JWT para java simple?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando implementar un token a un proyecto web usando las algunas de las librerías que son recomendadas por google. Ya usé una llamada "jjwt" la cual venía muy bien hasta que me empezó a tirar un error relacionado a las librerías jackson, las actualicé, bajé las últimas etc, no hay caso, me cambié a las JOSE nimbus que por lo visto son mejores, sin embargo no encuentro en la net un ejemplo que cuando lo paso a mi máquina funcione sin que me tire un error o que no reconozca algun métodos que debería tener la librería y que por lo visto las que bajé no lo traen.
Me estoy por rendir, si alguno me tira una linea mejor. Perdón por ser tan poco específico pero cuando estás hace un mes intentando que las clases no te tiren errores llega un momento que tocás fondo. gracias.
Este código es claramente una copia del ejemplo que tiene el autor de JJWT, sin embargo cuando lo quiero correr en un static void main para ver el String me tira un error.

```
package org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos;

import java.security.Key;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider;

public class ValidarToken {

    public String token(){
        // We need a signing key, so we'll create one just for this example. Usually
        // the key would be read from your application configuration instead.
        Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();

        String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
          .setSubject("Joe")
          .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key)
          .compact();

        return compactJws;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ValidarToken t= new ValidarToken();
        System.out.println(t.token());
    }

}
```

Y este es error que me tira:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:204)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:44)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:549)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:465)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:42)
at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116)
at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ValidarToken.token(ValidarToken.java:16)
at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ValidarToken.main(ValidarToken.java:27)
```

Algo de USE_DEFAULTS que parece que es de jackson apartir del 2.6 en adelante, el tema es que lo tengo actualizado y sin embargo sigue eso, no sé, es más las librerías jackson las tengo porque muchas cosas se basan en ellas, yo personalmente uso las Gson() para hacer json, pero bueno ahora tengo este problema y no lo puedo solucionar.

Comment: En verdad te causo problemas https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt ? yo lo uso pero no con Jackson.

Comment: mirá ahi voy a poner en la pregunta lo que venia haciendo...

Comment: @Jorgesys te hago una pregunta Jorge, a vos te anda bien el JJWT? porque ahora sí me anda pero sólo por consola, cuando lo quiero correr en el endpoint me tira error, las dependencias jackson ya las actualicé a las 2.8.2 y anda bien sólo por consola, así que me estoy empezando a preguntar si el problema es que mi jersey es 1.19 y no 2.0 como hay actualmente. En qué ambiente lo corrés y con qué configuración?

Comment: yo lo uso con jackson 2.8.4!, te recomiendo actualizarlo tal vez eso es el problema, de hecho veo que la última version es 2.8.8

Comment: @Jorgesys si, los jackson ya los tengo actualizados , es más, hice un upgrade a los jackson que decís vos, pero me está pareciendo que mi problema es el Jersey que estoy usando. vos cuál usas el jersey 1.19 o el 2.0 en adelante?

Comment: Ups! yo tengo 2.0 pero ya esta 2.17 :|

Comment: @Jorgesys Me parece que por ahi viene mi drama, sin embargo me anda tan bien el Jersey 1.19 que me da cosa cambiarlo sólo por el jjwt token, es un dilema zarpado. Mirá me fuiste de gran ayuda, sin embargo si podés date un vuelta por esta pregunta haber si encontrás algo en mi código que haya hecho mal, yo creo que está todo super ok, por eso me tiro a que el problema es el jersey.  [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64137/jjwt-java-token-funciona-bien-por-la-consola-pero-no-en-el-endpoint]