# JJWT java Token funciona bien por la consola pero no en el endpoint

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al tratar de simplemente mostrar el *token* creado por medio de un simple `alert` de javascript. Hice un método que crea el *token*, el cual funciona excelente, ya que cuando lo pruebo por "consola" el resultado es una linea larga de caracteres, oséa el String que esperaba. Sin embargo cuando quiero que el mismo pase por un endpoint con método que retorna un `String` y que haga algo tan simple como ser visualizado en en un `alert` no funciona. la razón por la que lo quiero mostrar en un `alert` es simplemente para saber que el servidor me está devolviendo correctamente el `String`. dejo los archivos y al final la lista de errores.

Este es el método que crea el Token(String):

```
public class ValidateToken{

    public static String createToken(String user){

        Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();
        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, key).compact();

    return token;
  }
}
```

Esta es la prueba por consola de que el método de arriba funciona bien(abajo hay una screenshot del token):

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String user="TokenTest";

    System.out.println(ValidateToken.createToken(user));
}
```

[image: Screenshot del token creado en "public static void main" consola no endpoint]

Este es el endpoint java:

```
@Path("/validateToken")
public class Autenticacion_stateless {

  @POST
  @Path("/validate")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  public String createToken(@FormParam("user") String user){

    String response= null;

        try
            {
                ValidateToken.createToken(user);
            }
            catch(SignatureException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("It does'nt work.");
                }

    return response;
 }

}
```

Esta es la llamada desde AJAX:
    function createToken(){

```
user= document.getElementById("user");

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "/Proyecto_Final_AAB/rest/validateToken/validate";

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("user="+user.value);
}
```

Este es el html con el input conectado al .js:
    
<   head>

```
<body>

    <input type="text" id="user">

    <input type="button" value="send" onclick="createToken()">

</body>
```

Y esta es la línea de errores:

```
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Proyecto_Final_AAB' did not find a matching property.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         7.0.75.0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 7
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            6.1
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          x86
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\user\Downloads\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32\eclipse;;.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8079"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8008"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 836 ms
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMACIÓN: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [146] milliseconds.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
abr 19, 2017 9:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:16 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFORMACIÓN: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
abr 19, 2017 9:19:18 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMACIÓN: Root resource classes found:
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarSuperAdministrador
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.AdminSeg
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.SuperAdmin
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.Administradores
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarAdministradorVuelo
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.Autenticacion_stateless
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarAdministradorSeguridad
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.AdminVuelos
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarUsuario
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.Empleados
abr 19, 2017 9:19:18 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMACIÓN: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
  class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
abr 19, 2017 9:19:18 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMACIÓN: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:42 PM'
abr 19, 2017 9:19:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8079"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8008"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 5375 ms
abr 19, 2017 9:19:34 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:549)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:465)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:42)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ValidarToken.crearToken(ValidarToken.java:25)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.Autenticacion_stateless.createToken(Autenticacion_stateless.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

abr 19, 2017 9:19:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Servlet_Aeropuerto] en el contexto con ruta [/Proyecto_Final_AAB] lanzó la excepción [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS] con causa raíz
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:549)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:465)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:42)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ValidarToken.crearToken(ValidarToken.java:25)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.Autenticacion_stateless.createToken(Autenticacion_stateless.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Archivo pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JJWT Token dependencias de github -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jHades classes deplicadas ispector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jhades</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhades</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jackson estás usando?

Comment: @kerten si no me equivoco es la 2.9.0, estuve con la 2.8.2 que es la que recomendaban en JJWT , sin embargo ahi dice desde la 2.8.2 en adelante. igualmente había probado con 2.8.2 y tuve el mismo problema realmente. Ahi subi el archivo pom.xml a la pregunta igual para que vean.

Comment: Puede que te falte esta dependencia:   

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0.pr2

Comment: claro que sí @berlot83

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando jersey-bundle versión 1.9 que a su vez utiliza una versión de jackson pasada por lo que existe conflictos con la versión que tu agregas.

Considera usar jersey-server

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
```

en lugar de

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: esta bien, pero en ese caso tendria que modificar el archivo web.xml no? ahi se me complica un poco la existencia en saber qué cambiar en ese archivo

Comment: En el repositorio de github encuentras un ejemplo para despliegue [ejemplo](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/servlet3-webapp)

Comment: bueno ya lo estoy leyendo, si efectivamente al cambio del 1.19 al 2.6  dejó de funcionar todo, espero poder arreglarlo y actualizarlo y que ese sea el problema de fondo.